# 301 redirect with .htaccess does not work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to setup following redirection:

```
From: http://www.contractorshire.co.uk/plant/attachments.asp
To: http://www.contractorshire.co.uk/catalog/plant/attachments/
```

Following entry in .htaccess does not work:

```
Redirect 301 /plant/attachments.asp /catalog/plant/attachments/
```

Any ideas why?

LG

Full .htaccess:

```
# Friendly URLs Part
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
# Force all pages to go to www.domain.com for SEO
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
# ASP Redirects
RewriteRule ^plant/attachments\.asp$ catalog/plant/attachments/[R=302,L]
# Additional Settings Follow
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

Answer (score 1):

I see quite a few people have problems with this method. Most resort to using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^plant/attachments\.asp$ catalog/plant/attachements/ [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, I think that `Redirect` requires an absolute destination path:

```
Redirect 301 /plant/attachments.asp http://contractorshire.co.uk/catalog/plant/attachments/
```

Comment: Hi Mike, it results with the following:
http://www.contractorshire.co.uk/contact-us.html?q=plant/attachments.asp

Comment: Please post your entire `.htaccess` file (if it isn't too big - try omit repetitions). Also, what link are you requesting in your `<a>` tag?

Comment: Please see my update - I've added an alternative redirect for you to try.

Comment: Mike, I have attached content of .htaccess.

The alternate redirect also does not work :(

Comment: I see - you'll need to move the redirect above the `Friendly URLs` part, and change `302` to `301`. (In fact, you may as well move it just below the `RewriteBase`.)

Comment: Very same results after making this change.

Comment: Weird indeed - perhaps @faa's solution will work - it looks like a better approach. The whole idea is to perform all necessary 301 redirects *before* performing any silent-rewrites.